# Salesforce Lightning component not getting record Id

Tags: lightning-aura-components

This is my issue:
I add ligtning component to a felixpage and I keep getting a null pointer on load (in the init method) where the record id of the current record is passed. When I debug component.get("v.recordId") it returns undefined.
I am using the header:

```
implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
```

The purpose of this component is to upload a file, and show a list of uploaded files.
Once I upload a new file it will work just fine. I will see a correct list of old files and everything but on load it does not pass the current record Id so the null pointer occurs.

Below is my doInit method that runs on load, the 1st log line returns undefined:

```javascript
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {

    console.log('recordId: ' + component.get("v.recordId"));
    console.log('RelatedToID: ' + component.get("v.RelatedToID"));


    var RefrenceField = component.get("v.RefrenceField");
    var accID = component.get("v.recordId"); // Get the account ID
    var RelatedToID = component.get("v.RelatedToID");
    var action = component.get("c.getRecordID"); //Call a APEX method to Check if all the required fields are filled.

    action.setParams({
        recID: component.get("v.recordId"), /* here it sends a null value*/
        'refrenceField' : RefrenceField
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                                console.log('HERE 2');

        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS"){
                    console.log('HERE 2');

            if(response.getReturnValue()!=null){
                                        console.log('HERE 3');

                component.set("v.RelatedToID",response.getReturnValue());
                component.fileMethod();
            }
        }
    });
},
```

I'm also adding the cmp file below:

```html
<aura:component controller="GenericFileUploderController" access="global" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:method name="fileMethod" action="{!c.getdocs}" description="controller function" />
    <aura:method name="clearvalues" action="{!c.clearvalues}" access="PUBLIC"/> <!-- method used to rerender component -->
    <aura:attribute name="RefrenceField" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="RelatedToID" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="DisplayAttachedFiles" type="boolean" default="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="files" type="ContentDocument[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="LabelText" type="string" default = "Attachment" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />

    <!--<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" description="Record to which the files should be attached" />-->
    <aura:attribute name="documentType" type="String" default="{ 'attachment' }"/>

    <lightning:fileUpload label="{!v.LabelText}"
        name="fileUploader"
        multiple="true"
        accept=".pdf, .png, .xls, .xlsx, .eml, .csv, .zip, .doc, .docx, .ppt, .pptx, .txt , .msg"
        recordId="{!v.RelatedToID}"
        onuploadfinished="{!c.handleUploadFinished}" />

    <!--<aura:if isTrue ="{!v.DisplayAttachedFiles}">-->
        <div class="slds-box">  
            <aura:iteration var="file" items="{!v.files}">

                <lightning:layout >
                    <lightning:layoutItem >       
                        <lightning:icon iconName="doctype:image" />
                    </lightning:layoutItem>
                    <lightning:layoutItem > 
                        <lightning:layoutItem class="slds-m-left_small"><ui:outputURL aura:id="oURL" target="_blank" label="{!file.Title}" value="{!'/' +file.Id}"/></lightning:layoutItem><br/>
                    </lightning:layoutItem>  
                    <lightning:layoutItem alignmentBump="left">
                        <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:delete" value="{!file.Id}" onclick="{!c.deleteFile}" alternativeText="Delete" />
                    </lightning:layoutItem>
                </lightning:layout>

            </aura:iteration>

        </div>
    <!--</aura:if>-->


</aura:component>
```

Apex code below:

```
@AuraEnabled   
public static string getRecordID(ID recID ,string refrenceField ) {
    string returnString;
    if(refrenceField!=null) {
        string sObjectName = recID.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
        String querystring = 'select id,' + refrenceField +' from '+sObjectName + ' where id = : recID';
        sObject sobjList = Database.query(queryString);
        string SDCCaseID = String.valueOf(sobjList.get(refrenceField));
            returnString = SDCCaseID;
        if(SDCCaseID!=null){
        }
    }
    else{
        returnString = recID; 
    }
    return returnString;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99310/discussion-on-question-by-muhammad-bajwa-salesforce-lightning-component-not-gett).

Comment: You should not put recordId attribute in your component, because it is defined by the force:hasRecordId interface automatically. Can you please try removing that attribute and running the component again.